# Django localization: my django.po file became empty after compiling

Tags: python, django, internationalization

After doing:
`django-admin.py compilemessages`

My django.po file became empty. All my translations are gone.
The compiled django.mo file is still there. I have a copy of my django.po on github but it's 1 day old.

Is there any way to decompile the django.mo to get the last added translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary *.mo files from gettext could be "decompiled" by using msgunfmt: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#msgunfmt-Invocation